# My first riddle on Puzzling Beta!

Tags: riddle

What am I?

```
As of today

I have roughly 3,700
I've been given roughly 10,300
I'm almost always complete!
I contain roughly 11,000
I get roughly 6,300
```

This is my first puzzle posted, so I'm very new, so bear with me.

**EDIT**
You guys are too good, I'll need to really make it tricky next time!

Comment: Why the rollback?

Comment: @Mithrandir Why the change? This riddle had a perfectly clever title to begin with which got changed to some generic nonsense. Ontop of it, this riddle hadn't been touched for over a year. Why go and bastardized dormant riddles that where accepted at initial release?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is:

> Referring to the Puzzling beta stats as of 9/17/2015

I have roughly 3,700

> It has 3,639 questions

I've been given roughly 10,300

> It has 10,318 answers

I'm almost always complete!

> Most of our questions have been completed.

I contain roughly 11,000

> There are 10,925 users

I get roughly 6,300

> The site gets 6,265 visitors/day.

Comment: Nice! Beat me to that last part too!

Comment: I can't believe we get that many visitors! Why are there not more puzzles??

Answer (score 6):

PARTIAL

You are:

> Puzzling StackExchange beta!

I have roughly 3,700

> There are 3640 questions as of this writing

I've been given roughly 10,300

> 10,318 answers

I contain roughly 11,000

> A quick estimate of users on the site gives me 10,440.

I get roughly 6,300

> 6,265 new visitors a day

Comment: Very quick!! I was hoping no one actually paid attention. I tried give a small hint in my title.

Comment: @Timmy I appreciate the acceptance, but alexmc has the more complete answer. You should accept his instead

Comment: Oops! Thanks for catching that honestly. I meant to accept Alex. I'm clicking around from my phone. Too small for me to comprehend.